# PersistenceUnit: default Unable to build Hibernate SessionFactory - Hibernate

Tags: java, xml, spring, hibernate, maven

when I start tomcat I get the following error:

```
org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'entityManagerFactory' defined in ServletContext resource [/WEB-INF/spring-context.xml]: Invocation of init method failed; nested exception is javax.persistence.PersistenceException: [PersistenceUnit: default] Unable to build Hibernate SessionFactory
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.initializeBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1574)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:539)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:476)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory$1.getObject(AbstractBeanFactory.java:303)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:230)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:299)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:194)
at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.getBean(AbstractApplicationContext.java:956)
at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.finishBeanFactoryInitialization(AbstractApplicationContext.java:747)
at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.refresh(AbstractApplicationContext.java:480)
at org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoader.configureAndRefreshWebApplicationContext(ContextLoader.java:403)
at org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoader.initWebApplicationContext(ContextLoader.java:306)
at org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoaderListener.contextInitialized(ContextLoaderListener.java:106)
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.listenerStart(StandardContext.java:5016)
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.startInternal(StandardContext.java:5528)
at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:150)
at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase$StartChild.call(ContainerBase.java:1575)
at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase$StartChild.call(ContainerBase.java:1565)
at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:262)
at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1145)
at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:615)
at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
Caused by: javax.persistence.PersistenceException: [PersistenceUnit: default] Unable to build Hibernate SessionFactory
at org.hibernate.jpa.boot.internal.EntityManagerFactoryBuilderImpl.persistenceException(EntityManagerFactoryBuilderImpl.java:954)
at org.hibernate.jpa.boot.internal.EntityManagerFactoryBuilderImpl.build(EntityManagerFactoryBuilderImpl.java:884)
at org.springframework.orm.jpa.vendor.SpringHibernateJpaPersistenceProvider.createContainerEntityManagerFactory(SpringHibernateJpaPersistenceProvider.java:60)
at org.springframework.orm.jpa.LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean.createNativeEntityManagerFactory(LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean.java:343)
at org.springframework.orm.jpa.AbstractEntityManagerFactoryBean.afterPropertiesSet(AbstractEntityManagerFactoryBean.java:318)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.invokeInitMethods(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1633)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.initializeBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1570)
... 21 more
Caused by: org.hibernate.MappingException: Could not get constructor for org.hibernate.persister.entity.SingleTableEntityPersister
at org.hibernate.persister.internal.PersisterFactoryImpl.createEntityPersister(PersisterFactoryImpl.java:123)
at org.hibernate.persister.internal.PersisterFactoryImpl.createEntityPersister(PersisterFactoryImpl.java:77)
at org.hibernate.internal.SessionFactoryImpl.<init>(SessionFactoryImpl.java:344)
at org.hibernate.boot.internal.SessionFactoryBuilderImpl.build(SessionFactoryBuilderImpl.java:465)
at org.hibernate.jpa.boot.internal.EntityManagerFactoryBuilderImpl.build(EntityManagerFactoryBuilderImpl.java:881)
... 26 more
 Caused by: org.hibernate.InstantiationException: could not instantiate test object : br.gov.sp.saobernardo.sispront.solicitacao.Solicitacao
at org.hibernate.engine.internal.UnsavedValueFactory.instantiate(UnsavedValueFactory.java:43)
at org.hibernate.engine.internal.UnsavedValueFactory.getUnsavedIdentifierValue(UnsavedValueFactory.java:68)
at org.hibernate.tuple.PropertyFactory.buildIdentifierAttribute(PropertyFactory.java:61)
at org.hibernate.tuple.entity.EntityMetamodel.<init>(EntityMetamodel.java:138)
at org.hibernate.persister.entity.AbstractEntityPersister.<init>(AbstractEntityPersister.java:509)
at org.hibernate.persister.entity.SingleTableEntityPersister.<init>(SingleTableEntityPersister.java:124)
at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance0(Native Method)
at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.java:57)
at sun.reflect.DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.java:45)
at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:526)
at org.hibernate.persister.internal.PersisterFactoryImpl.createEntityPersister(PersisterFactoryImpl.java:96)
... 30 more
Caused by: java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException
at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance0(Native Method)
at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.java:57)
at sun.reflect.DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.java:45)
at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:526)
at org.hibernate.engine.internal.UnsavedValueFactory.instantiate(UnsavedValueFactory.java:40)
... 40 more
Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException
at br.gov.sp.saobernardo.sispront.solicitacao.Solicitacao.<init>(Solicitacao.java:86)
... 45 more
```

I googled the error in various forums and StackOverFlow but I found no solution and still have the same error, below the class Solicitacao.class, pom.xml, spring-context.xml, persistence.xml

```
package br.gov.sp.saobernardo.sispront.solicitacao;

import java.util.Calendar;

import javax.persistence.Entity;
import javax.persistence.EnumType;
import javax.persistence.Enumerated;
import javax.persistence.FetchType;
import javax.persistence.GeneratedValue;
import javax.persistence.GenerationType;
import javax.persistence.Id;
import javax.persistence.JoinColumn;
import javax.persistence.ManyToOne;
import javax.persistence.PrePersist;
import javax.persistence.SequenceGenerator;
import javax.persistence.Temporal;
import javax.persistence.TemporalType;
import javax.validation.constraints.NotNull;

import org.hibernate.validator.constraints.NotBlank;
import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;
import org.springframework.format.annotation.DateTimeFormat;

import br.gov.sp.saobernardo.sispront.usuario.Usuario; 

@Entity
public class Solicitacao {

@Id
@Autowired
@GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.SEQUENCE, generator = "sq_solicitacao")
@SequenceGenerator(name = "sq_solicitacao", sequenceName = "sq_solicitacao", allocationSize = 1, initialValue = 1)
private Long id;

@NotBlank(message = "{solicitacao.cadastro.nome.obrigatorio}")
private String nome;

@NotBlank(message = "{solicitacao.cadastro.mae.obrigatorio}")
private String mae;

@NotBlank(message = "{solicitacao.cadastro.rg.obrigatorio}")
private String rg;

@DateTimeFormat(pattern = "dd/MM/yyyy")
private Calendar dataNascimento;

@DateTimeFormat(pattern = "dd/MM/yyyy")
private Calendar dataAtendimento;

private String motivo;

private String horario;

private String local;

@NotBlank(message = "{solicitacao.cadastro.telefone.obrigatorio}")
private String telefone;

private String celular;

@NotNull(message = "{solicitacao.cadastro.internacao.obrigatorio}")
private Boolean internacao;

private Double dias;

private String nomeSolicitante;

private String rgSolicitante;

private String observacao;

@Enumerated(EnumType.STRING)
private Status status;

@ManyToOne(fetch=FetchType.LAZY)
@JoinColumn(name="autor_id")
private Usuario autor;

private String unidade;

@Temporal(TemporalType.TIMESTAMP)
private Calendar data;

public Solicitacao() {
    status = Status.Aguardando_Levantamento_de_Ficha;
    setUnidade(autor.getUnidade());
}

@PrePersist
void prePersist() {
    data = Calendar.getInstance();
}
GET's AND SET's
```

pom.xml

```
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0    http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
<modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
<groupId>br.gov.sp.saobernardo</groupId>
<artifactId>sispront</artifactId>
<version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
<packaging>war</packaging>
<name>SisPRONT</name>
<url>http://www.saobernardo.sp.gov.br/saude</url>

<properties>
    <spring.version>4.1.6.RELEASE</spring.version>
    <spring-security.version>4.0.1.RELEASE</spring-security.version>
</properties>

<dependencies>
    <!-- Dependências do Spring -->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-aop</artifactId>
        <version>${spring.version}</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-context-support</artifactId>
        <version>${spring.version}</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-tx</artifactId>
        <version>${spring.version}</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-orm</artifactId>
        <version>${spring.version}</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-oxm</artifactId>
        <version>${spring.version}</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-webmvc</artifactId>
        <version>${spring.version}</version>
    </dependency>
    <!-- <dependency> -->
    <!-- <groupId>org.springframework</groupId> -->
    <!-- <artifactId>spring-test</artifactId> -->
    <!-- <version>${spring.version}</version> -->
    <!-- <scope>test</scope> -->
    <!-- </dependency> -->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.security</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-security-web</artifactId>
        <version>${spring-security.version}</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.security</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-security-config</artifactId>
        <version>${spring-security.version}</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.security</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-security-taglibs</artifactId>
        <version>${spring-security.version}</version>
    </dependency>
    <!-- Dependências do Hibernate -->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.hibernate</groupId>
        <artifactId>hibernate-entitymanager</artifactId>
        <version>5.1.0.Final</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.hibernate</groupId>
        <artifactId>hibernate-validator</artifactId>
        <version>5.2.4.Final</version>
    </dependency>
    <!-- Dependência do driver JDBC do Oracle -->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.oracle</groupId>
        <artifactId>ojdbc14</artifactId>
        <version>10.2.0.4.0</version>
    </dependency>
    <!-- Dependência para upload de arquivos pelo SpringMVC -->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>commons-fileupload</groupId>
        <artifactId>commons-fileupload</artifactId>
        <version>1.3.1</version>
    </dependency>
    <!-- Dependência de EL para Servlet Container -->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>javax.servlet</groupId>
        <artifactId>jstl</artifactId>
        <version>1.2</version>
    </dependency>
    <!-- Dependências para envio de email -->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>javax.mail</groupId>
        <artifactId>mail</artifactId>
        <version>1.4.7</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.apache.velocity</groupId>
        <artifactId>velocity</artifactId>
        <version>1.7</version>
    </dependency>
    <!-- Dependências de log -->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.slf4j</groupId>
        <artifactId>slf4j-log4j12</artifactId>
        <version>1.5.8</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>log4j</groupId>
        <artifactId>log4j</artifactId>
        <version>1.2.17</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.google.guava</groupId>
        <artifactId>guava</artifactId>
        <version>18.0</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.google.code.gson</groupId>
        <artifactId>gson</artifactId>
        <version>2.3.1</version>
    </dependency>
    <!-- Dependências da especificação de Servlet -->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>javax.servlet</groupId>
        <artifactId>javax.servlet-api</artifactId>
        <version>3.0.1</version>
        <scope>provided</scope>
    </dependency>
    <!-- <dependency> -->
    <!-- <groupId>br.gov.sp.saobernardo</groupId> -->
    <!-- <artifactId>arquivo</artifactId> -->
    <!-- <version>1.0-SNAPSHOT</version> -->
    <!-- </dependency> -->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.hamcrest</groupId>
        <artifactId>hamcrest-all</artifactId>
        <version>1.3</version>
        <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.h2database</groupId>
        <artifactId>h2</artifactId>
        <version>1.4.188</version>
        <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.hibernate.javax.persistence</groupId>
        <artifactId>hibernate-jpa-2.1-api</artifactId>
        <version>1.0.0.Final</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>commons-digester</groupId>
        <artifactId>commons-digester</artifactId>
        <version>2.1</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>joda-time</groupId>
        <artifactId>joda-time</artifactId>
        <version>2.9</version>
    </dependency>

</dependencies>

<build>
    <finalName>sispront</finalName>
    <plugins>
        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
            <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>3.1</version>
            <configuration>
                <source>1.7</source>
                <target>1.7</target>
            </configuration>
        </plugin>
    </plugins>
</build>
```

spring-context.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:context="http://www.springframework.org/schema/context"
xmlns:tx="http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx" xmlns:mvc="http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc"
xmlns:jee="http://www.springframework.org/schema/jee" xmlns:security="http://www.springframework.org/schema/security"
xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc
http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc/spring-mvc-4.1.xsd
http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans
http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans-4.1.xsd
http://www.springframework.org/schema/context
http://www.springframework.org/schema/context/spring-context-4.1.xsd
http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx
http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx/spring-tx-4.1.xsd
http://www.springframework.org/schema/jee
http://www.springframework.org/schema/jee/spring-jee-4.1.xsd
http://www.springframework.org/schema/security
http://www.springframework.org/schema/security/spring-security-4.0.xsd">

<context:component-scan base-package="br.gov.sp.saobernardo.sispront" />

<mvc:annotation-driven />

<mvc:default-servlet-handler />

<jee:jndi-lookup jndi-name="jdbc/dahue" id="oracleDataSource" />

<bean
    class="org.springframework.web.servlet.view.InternalResourceViewResolver">
    <property name="prefix" value="/WEB-INF/views/" />
    <property name="suffix" value=".jsp" />
</bean>

<bean id="entityManagerFactory"
    class="org.springframework.orm.jpa.LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean">
    <property name="dataSource" ref="oracleDataSource" />
    <property name="jpaVendorAdapter">
        <bean class="org.springframework.orm.jpa.vendor.HibernateJpaVendorAdapter" />
    </property>
</bean>

<bean id="transactionManager" class="org.springframework.orm.jpa.JpaTransactionManager">
    <property name="entityManagerFactory" ref="entityManagerFactory" />
</bean>

<bean id="messageSource"
    class="org.springframework.context.support.ReloadableResourceBundleMessageSource">
    <property name="useCodeAsDefaultMessage" value="true" />
    <property name="basenames">
        <list>
            <value>classpath:ValidationMessages</value>
        </list>
    </property>
    <property name="defaultEncoding" value="ISO-8859-1"></property>
    <property name="cacheSeconds" value="0" />
</bean>

<tx:annotation-driven />

<security:authentication-manager>
    <security:authentication-provider
        user-service-ref="usuarioDAO">
        <security:password-encoder hash="bcrypt" />
    </security:authentication-provider>
</security:authentication-manager>

<security:http auto-config="true" use-expressions="true">
    <security:intercept-url pattern="/a/**"
        access="hasRole('ROLE_LOGADO')" />

    <security:form-login login-page="/log-in"
        always-use-default-target="true" default-target-url="/a/solicitacao/home"
        login-processing-url="/log-in" username-parameter="registro"
        password-parameter="senha" />
    <security:logout logout-url="/a/log-out"
        logout-success-url="/log-in" delete-cookies="JSESSIONID"
        invalidate-session="true" />
</security:http>

<security:global-method-security
    secured-annotations="enabled" />
```

persistence.xml

```
<persistence xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/persistence"
xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/persistence
http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/persistence/persistence_2_0.xsd"
version="2.0">
<persistence-unit name="default">
    <provider>org.hibernate.ejb.HibernatePersistence</provider>

    <class>br.gov.sp.saobernardo.sispront.usuario.Usuario</class>
    <class>br.gov.sp.saobernardo.sispront.papel.Papel</class>
    <class>br.gov.sp.saobernardo.sispront.solicitacao.historico.Alteracao</class>
    <class>br.gov.sp.saobernardo.sispront.solicitacao.Solicitacao</class>

    <properties>
        <property name="hibernate.dialect" value="org.hibernate.dialect.Oracle9iDialect" />
        <property name="hibernate.show_sql" value="false" />
        <property name="hibernate.format_sql" value="true" />
        <property name="hibernate.hbm2ddl.auto" value="update" />
    </properties>
</persistence-unit>
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

`autor` is `null` in the constructor. Hibernate while process the mapping creates temporary objects of classes using `Class<?>.createInstance()`. In this situation a default constructor is invoked

```
public Solicitacao() {
    status = Status.Aguardando_Levantamento_de_Ficha;
    setUnidade(autor.getUnidade());
}
```

Comment: Thanks'm starting and still do not know to interpret the log errors, but that was it, thank you, you took the rope from my neck

Comment: @ViniciusDuarte You are welcome. Always begin from the end of a stack trace `Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException
at br.gov.sp.saobernardo.sispront.solicitacao.Solicitacao.<init>(Solicitacao.java:86)`. Look at the line with a specified number.